# Install requirements from pip with minimum possible version

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

I am trying to install a complicated project on Python 3.4.3. The problem is that a lot of dependencies have dependencies that use the `dependency>=version` syntax. This ends up having pip trying to install the greatest possible package version greater than said version. I was wondering if there is a general pip command that allows me to treat `dependency>=version` as `dependency==version`, basically installing the minimum possible version.

Comment: Couldn't you just install the package first, then pip install the package's dependencies directly with the minimum possible version?

Comment: How would I install package dependencies with minimum possible version? I'm trying to find something general for anything with a requirements.txt.

Comment: Are you installing using a requirements.txt?

Comment: @xpie Yes, I'm installing project dependencies from requirements.txt.

Comment: What about do a replacement? I mean replace all the '>' with '='

Comment: @xpie I would, but that doesn't affect the sub-dependencies of the dependencies listed in requirements.txt.

Comment: Sorry I cant understand clearly, what do you mean by the sub-dependencies

Comment: @xpie By sub-dependencies, I mean like each dependency as its own dependencies to install as well.

Comment: I suppose you can write a replace.py which can replace all the '>'s in the requirements.txt. Won't it work using the new requirements.txt?

Comment: @xpie No, but the subdependencies are not in the requirements.txt, And those are the ones using the >= syntax.

Answer (score 0):

After a bit of research, I came across a tool called `pip-compile`, included in pip package `pip-tools`. Using,

`pip-compile requirements.txt`

I was able to generate a requirements.txt file easily.